# is it possible to run a command before git checkout

Tags: git, githooks, git-checkout

every user is logged in with credentials working on a local repo he created branch.

So if that user's path is shared with other anyone probably can navigate to that path and type `git checkout  .` that would undo all the changes done by the user sitting on different machine with different login but having access to same path where local repo is.

So I want to be able to reject the checkout if the user executing the `git checkout` command is different then the one who created the local repo at that path. So far I found git hook that executes post-checkout

i.e. checkout succeeded. and do the other things.
So anyone have any idea how this can be achieved to just execute the command before checkout to just reject if user name doesnt matches ?

Comment: Why can user A write to a directory created by user B?  This sounds like a solution for permissions and umask, not your version control system.  Can you expand a little on why this problem occurs?

Comment: a few days back my work got lost , as I left office with uncommitted changes, now I didn't  had any proof / any idea how that happen, but I was doubting since the path can easily be accessed by anyone somebody could have run `git checkout .` navigating to that path.

Comment: Interesting.  I think it would be interesting to test this hypothesis, because it would certainly be easier to change the permissions so that other users can't do this to you (versus trying to make Git deal with this problem).

Comment: there won't be issue with permission if I stored it on my user directory but since the office user directory is on a different server and server often goes down I store my local repo on system disk , and every system disk is accessible from anywhere if machine name is known.

Answer (score 1):

> So anyone have any idea how this can be achieved to just execute the command before checkout to just reject if user name doesnt matches ?

Git doesn't deal with authentication and authorization, only with file control management.

> a few days back my work got lost , as I left office with uncommitted changes, now I didn't had any proof / any idea how that happen

Then it is best to have a scheduled task which execute a [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), or to have a backup process for the working tree (in the shared path).

Comment: I accept the `git stash` idea, however you mean to say we can't have a  way to have a git hook that does a check or can call any other bash or python script, in my own script I can check with user performing `git checkout` and compare from the local repo owner's info from `.git` folder.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz the problem with such a "check" is to find the user id (authentication), in order for the "check" to allow or deny an operation (authorization). Git itself doesn't know anything about who does an operation. So unless you access your shared repo through another protocol (https or ssh) which does the authentication for you and then call an authorization layer like gitolite (http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#overview), you won't get a "check" natively from Git alone.

Answer (score 0):

Think about

```
git clean -fdx //remove all untracked files
git reset // a waste array of options that could nullify your recent work
```

This is a permission question, not git hook. Just change the permissions or name the parent golder to GIT to contain some threats in case of malicious actions :)